# Django-nose --with-profile getting no results ("0 function calls")

Tags: django, unit-testing, nose, django-nose

I'm trying to diagnose some slow running unit tests, but I'm not having any luck getting the profiler working with [django-nose](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose). I came up with a repo case on a brand new Django project.

```
django-admin.py startproject nosetest
cd nosetest/

virtualenv --no-site-packages --distribute virtualenv
source virtualenv/bin/activate
pip install django_nose

echo "
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': ':memory',
    },
}

INSTALLED_APPS = INSTALLED_APPS + ('django_nose', )

TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
" >> nosetest/settings.py

echo "
import unittest
import time

class SlowTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_slow(self):
        self.assertFalse(time.sleep(1))
" > nosetest/test.py

python manage.py test --with-profile
```

This should create a new Django project in the current directory, install some dependencies in a virtualenv, create a valid settings.py and then run a new unit test.

I'm expecting to see various function calls in the output. Instead, I'm getting the following:

```
nosetests --verbosity 1 --with-profile
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
.
         0 function calls in 0.000 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        0    0.000             0.000          profile:0(profiler)


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 1.002s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I have tried the cProfiler with [nose-cprof](https://github.com/msherry/nose-cprof), but that is giving similar results. Can anyone get this same project working, or point me to another solution for profiling this test?

Comment: Same issue here.  I see you reported it to the django-nose issue tracker: https://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose/issues/82